# PHP get the letter

Tags: php, regex, string

Variable `$name` (string) gives something like (possible values):

```
"Elton John"
"2012"
" George Bush"
" Julia"
"Marry III Great"
```

Want to catch the first letter of `$name` and add it to `$letter` variable.

It's important how many words (divided with spaces " ") the string has:

1. If there is just one word, set `$letter` to the first letter of the first word.
2. If there is more than one word, set `$letter` to the first letter of the second word.
3. If `$name` is empty, set `$letter` to `'undefined'`.

Thanks.

Comment: my php knowledge isn't good, don't know how to parse the first word, thats why I'm asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$names = explode(' ', trim($name));
if (empty($names))
    $letters = 'undefined';
else if(count($names)==1)
    $letters = substr($names[0],0,1);
else 
    $letters = substr($names[1],0,1);
```

Comment: You could also return `$names[1][0]` instead of using `substr()`.

Answer (score 3):

You could just do an explode or a preg_split and count the pieces:

```
$parts = preg_split('/\s/', $subject, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
if (count($parts) == 1)
   ...
```

An alternative with explode:

```
$subject = trim(subject);
$parts = explode(' ', $subject);
```

This works too if you are certain there are only spaces.

Comment: thanks, but it won't work if there is a whitespace before first word (it can be so, users choice).

Comment: @Ignatz Both work fine; `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` stops `preg_split` from returning empty blocks in the first code snippet, and `trim` removes the whitespace from the ends in the second

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use

```
$letter = $name{0};
```